# How to preserve content author and date/time when importing into IBM Connections using API

Tags: data-migration, connection

I need to import content into IBM Connections but it seems that the API ignores use of the author and any date/time information e.g. created/last modified.  I don't want to see all the migrated content having an Author of "SysAdmin" and a create/modified date of today!

Anyone know if there's a way to preserve the author name and date/time fields?

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that. Got no solution (unfortunately).

According to the IBM Connections wiki, the elements  and  are ignored on update.

See for example the [Wiki page for an activity entry](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Entry_content_ic45&content=pdcontent).